# How to send emails with get_connection method in django?

Tags: python, django, email, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send emails. First i am creating connection instance with get connection method. And then getting desire email host credentials from db. the connection instance is creating and all flow is going good but i am not receiving email on my email address. no error is raising..

**Step one:(passing email host object in connection function)**

```
def send_mass_html_mail_dynamic(email_object,request_data,template=None):
    email_host = EmailHost.objects.if_exists(request_data["email_host"])
    connection = email_connection(email_host) #here is connection function that returns connection object.
```

**Step two:(creating connection with the credentials of email host)**

```
def email_connection(email_host=None):
    if email_host:
        password = decypt(email_host.password)
        print("password :",password)
        print("ssl :",email_host.use_ssl)
        connection = get_connection(
            host=email_host.host,
            username=email_host.email, 
            password=password, 
            port=email_host.port, 
            use_tls =email_host.use_tls, 
            use_ssl =email_host.use_ssl, 
            fail_silently=False
            )
    return connection
```

**step three(send messages with connection object)**

```
.....
messages = [message1,message2]
print("reached to connect send instance")
connection.send_messages(messages)
print("sent to all")
```

-->send to all is printing with no error...but im email is not receiving in my email address... I have triple checked email host credentials and also print them they are correct.

Comment: Did you check if `email_host` exists?

Comment: yes that exists. as i mentioned i printed host credentials

Comment: do i have an alternative way to creating connection instance and send emails with that ?